# Datagrid - Format total count 100003 to 1M+ in Material UI with Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

I'm implementing Datagrid in Mui with reactjs. I have 1M data.
So I'm currently showing 100000 in total count.

Is there any way to show total count as 1M+ or 1000+ or any other shorthand ways to display a large number?

Please find the attached image for your reference.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this gives you a clarity.
Try passing the value like this for millions

```
value >= 1000000 && Math.abs(Number(your value here....)) / 1.0e6).toFixed(1) + " M+"
```

Comment: Where to use this? We are providing rowCount as total value. Can't assign a string to this field.

Comment: Set the row count in a variable or state and pass it in the above code then render it with custom row count

Comment: Is there any valueFormatter? Can you please provide the line of code for formatting? I need to do it without creating custom Footer.

Comment: Without creating a custom footer you can't format 1000000 to 1M as the rowCount prop only allows you to pass numbers and I have already provided you the code for formatting. If you found any solution without creating a custom footer please do share

Comment: Got it. Sure, will share.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this by displaying `1k` or `1m` accordingly if value it out of range.

```
const formatTotalCount = (params) => {
  const totalCount = params.value;
  if (totalCount >= 1000000) {
    return `${(totalCount / 1000000).toFixed(1)}M+`;
  } else if (totalCount >= 1000) {
    return `${(totalCount / 1000).toFixed(1)}K+`;
  } else {
    return totalCount.toString();
  }
};

const columns = [
  { field: 'totalCount', headerName: 'Total Count', width: 150, renderCell: formatTotalCount },
];

const rows = [
  // Your data rows here
];

const MyDataGrid = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={5} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyDataGrid;
```

Comment: This is not a column. It is footer part of Datagrid

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and did it without needing to create a custom footer component.

On your data grid slot props, you can override the pagination prop 'labelDisplayedRows' which format how the pagination labels are displayed. You can create a formatting function like the basic one I put in the example, and format the labels as you need them

See the [API reference](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/table-pagination/) for more information on labelDisplayedRows

```
const formatLargeNumber = (value: number) => {
    return value > 1000000 ? '1M+' : value
}

<DataGridPro
    ...
    slotProps={{
        pagination: {
            labelDisplayedRows: (page) =>
                `${formatLargeNumber(page.from)}-
                ${formatLargeNumber(page.to) === -1 ? 
                formatLargeNumber(page.count) : page.to} of ${page.count}`}
            }}
/>
```